I'm making facebook share button on my next.js project. Image is not appearing on shared contents
The developer tools shows no issue. it also shows the correct URL as og:image. But in the actual sharing content don't fetch the image. I suspect the image source issue which is the storyblok. Because when I hard-code an image from different domain, it works.
